# Apache dummy connections, Django, mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, dreamhost

I'm running a site using Django in a shared environment (Dreamhost), but 1.4 in a local environment.

Somtimes, I get hit by many, many Apache dummy connections (e.g., `[10/Jul/2012:00:49:16 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 136 "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"`
), which makes the site non-responsive (either it gets killed for resource consumption or max connections).

This does not happen on other sites on this account (though none are running Django). I'm trying to figure out a way to prevent this from happening, but I'm not sure what trouble-shooting process to use. Guidance on process or common sources of this issue would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Limit OPTIONS>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Limit>
```

This would cause a 403 forbidden to be returned by Apache and would not be handed off to any Django application if the issue is that they are getting through to the application at the moment.